# Получить команды LaTeX, нарисовав формулу от руки

Tags: математика, latex, tex

Существует сайт, где можно рукописно нарисовать математический символ, и получить соответствующую команду для тех'а. Например, если нарисовать зеркальную буковку "э" (символ принадлежности), сайт выдаст "\in". Что это за сайт?

Comment: https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html ?

Comment: Да, оно! Большущее спасибо. Оформите, пожалуйста, как ответ!